# Passing a custom internal url to window.open without specifying the domain name

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I am currently doing this

```
  __CHILD_WINDOW_HANDLE = window.open('http://localhost:59304/pageB', '_blank', 'width=700,height=500,left=200,top=100');
```

However I do not want to hard code `http://localhost:59304/` in my `window.open`
Is there a way to get this part during run time?

Comment: Just do `window.open('/pageB', '_blank', 'width=700,height=500,left=200,top=100');`

Comment: @fiveelements that did the trick. Can you put that as the answer

Comment: Glad to know. Added the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comment of the original post, if you specify the relative path, it automatically takes `protocol, host, and port` from the address bar (`window.location`) and makes the absolute URL:

```
window.open('/pageB', '_blank', 'width=700,height=500,left=200,top=100');
```